# INSERT INTO ... SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a big table(more than 60k rows), I am trying to copy unique rows from this table to another table. Query is as follows

```
INSERT INTO tbl2(field1, field2) 
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 
   FROM tbl1;
```

But it is taking ages to run this query, can someone suggest any way to accelerate this process

Comment: escalate? accelerate? Can you share the execution plan of the statement?

Comment: Execution plan as in? This statement is part of a migration file if you are asking that

Comment: Under the hood this may be executed as a `GROUP BY` query on the two fields.  In this case, it would require a full table scan and an index would not be helpful.

Comment: I'm puzzled by this, tests on my low(ish) spec home pc for 62,000 records (consisting of a union to the same table of 31,000 records each) completes in less than 3 secs, even without indexes and similar test up to 120,000 records are acceptable. The inserts by the way seem to take longer than the de-dupes. Note - I know this won't help unless it generates meaningful comment form other contributors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a mysqldump of your table, generating a sql file, then filter duplicated data with a shell command:

```
cat dump.sql | uniq > dump_filtered.sql
```

Check the generated file. Then create your new table and load your dump_filtered.sql file with [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1. drop the destination table: DROP DESTINATION_TABLE;
2. CREATE TABLE DESTINATION_TABLE AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE);
```